# Block the Excel message "content that is not suported" using AppleScript

Tags: excel, macos, applescript, excel-2008

I have an Excel 2008 file. This give a warning message when opened. I would like this message not to be displayed.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"  
    open workbook workbook file name "private:var:root:Desktop:XLS FILES:Copy of 
                                   New Microsoft Excel Worksheet (5).xlsx" read only 1
end tell
```

With the above script the Excel file is opened but the Excel warning still appears:

[image: SO14994693 question example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    open workbook workbook file name "private:var:root:Desktop:XLS FILES:Copy of New Microsoft Excel Worksheet (5).xlsx" with ignore read only recommended
end tell
```

Comment: My problem in office 2008 not 2011.

Comment: your script is open excel file with prompt excel message.